# Prove np-hardness of dividing items from the lists

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, np-hard, colorings

I have the following problem.

Given a finite number of lists of items. The same item can appear in many lists. I would like to color items with **3** colors, such at least two colors appear in each list.

I would like to show that this problem is NP-hard. I would like to provide reduction from the 3-coloring problem which seems to be similar.

I think I could make items as nodes and link every item with every other from the shared lists, but then the condition of 3-coloring would be too demanding in comparison to my problem. What should I do differently in order to create the reduction?

Comment: Try lists of size 2.

Comment: What do you mean? Items are not movable.

Comment: Are you trying to reduce in the wrong direction?

Comment: I hope I am not. I want to reduce from 3 coloring to my problem. Input to my problem are the lists of items to color.

Comment: Given an instance of 3-coloring, you need to produce an instance of your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that a problem is NP-hard, we need to reduce an NP-hard problem to it (which in this case as you mentioned would be 3-coloring).

So what we are trying to do, is to map every graph $G(V,E)$ to an instance of your problem, where every node $v_i$ will be mapped with an element $el(v_i)$ and every edge $\epsilon\{v_1, v_2\}$ would be represented with a two-element list $\{el(v_1), el(v_2)\}$.

So now a coloring $f:V\rightarrow C$ would be reduced to a coloring on the set of elements in your problem which means, if we found a coloring on the elements of the proposed problem, we can use the same coloring on our graph and it would be a proper coloring.

Proof.
If $f:V\rightarrow C$ isn't a proper coloring, that means there is an edge with both nodes having the same color, which means there is a set with two elements and both of them have the same color which contradicts the statement of your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @narek-bojikian I understand almost everything. I would like to ask about this part: _"every edge would be represented with a two-element list containing the maps of nodes of the edge"_. The word edge appears twice and I am not sure what edge do you mean at the end of this quote.

Comment: @pw94 i've just re-edited the explanation, hope it's clear now